# Is there a way to paste the output of this GoogleSkript into cells next to each other instead of below each other?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

This function splits the content of the input cell after every nth character. If the cell is longer than the defined n, then the additional outputs are pasted below the cell with the function. Is there a chance to also paste the outputs into the cells to the right?
Thanks!!!!

```
function SplitEveryNth (input, num) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i += num) {
    result.push(input.substr(i, num));
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you need to use the spreadsheet. For example you can fill first column, and then run a script. The ccript will count characters and put them in next cells.

Comment: I do not need to use the sheet so this would be an option. Could you help me with the skript?

Comment: Does NaziA's answer work fine for you?

Answer (score 0):

Use `return [result];` instead of `return result;` so it can return a row equivalent of the data.

#### Code:

```
function SplitEveryNth (input, num) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i += num) {
    result.push(input.substr(i, num));
  }
  return [result];
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]